# swift search array backwards

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that I want to search backwards. I am interested in the resulting index for the original array, not the actual value.  How can I convert a ReverseRandomAccessIndex to a "normal" index?

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
if let index = arr.reverse().indexOf(2) //index is ReverseRandomAccessIndex
{
 let searchvalue = arr.reverse()[index]
}
```

Comment: `NormalIndex = (Count - 1) - ReverseIndex`, maybe?

Comment: You can't get the index directly. It's a ReverseRandomAccessIndex. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if let index = arr.reverse().indexOf(2)
{
    let searchvalue = arr[index.base - 1]
}
```

`base`, as defined in the standard library:

```
    /// The successor position in the underlying (un-reversed)
    /// collection.
    ///
    /// If `self` is `advance(c.reverse.startIndex, n)`, then:
    /// - `self.base` is `advance(c.endIndex, -n)`.
    /// - if `n` != `c.count`, then `c.reverse[self]` is 
    ///   equivalent to `[self.base.predecessor()]`.
    public let base: Base
```